# Newline in FileWriter

Tags: java

How do you produce a new line in FileWriter? It seems that "\n" does not work.

```
log = new FileWriter("c:\\" + s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + ".txt", true);    
log.append("\n" + Long.toString(fileTransferTime));
log.close();
```

The file output of the code above is just a long string of numbers without the new line.

Comment: Is the \t in the second line a typo or intentional? Because \n should work - AFAIK.

Comment: Your code does not include any `\n`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "\n". I changed it to \t because it seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, all the answers now refer to the `\t` question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess that you're opening the `.txt` file in Notepad, which won't show newlines with just `\n`.

Have you tried using your system-specific newline character combination?

```
log.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + Long.toString(fileTransferTime));
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! Just found out that Notepad does not show "\n" newlines whereas other editors will. The System.getProperty("line.separator") does the job even if opened in Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

You should either encapsulate your `FileWriter` into a `PrintWriter` if your goal is to have a formated content, `println()` will help you. Or use the system property `line.separator` to have a separator adapted to your Operating System.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

---

**Resources :**

- [JavaDoc - PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println())
- [JavaDoc - Properties available on `System.getProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())

Answer (score 2):

I'm using "\r\n" and it works great for me. Even when opening .txt document in notepad;)

Comment: To be platform independent you should not hardcode this. E.g. Unix systems use `\n`. And it's a shame that so much people upvoted this as the other answers are way better.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `\t` to `\n` in the second line.