# Inserting New Lines when Writing to a Text File in Java

Tags: java

I have a slight delema with learning FileWriter...  The ultimate goal is writing a program that will "spawn" a .bat file that will be executed by the batch code that launched the .jar.  The problem is, I have no clue how to make sure that every FileWriter.write(); will print on a new line...  Any ideas??

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596766/newline-in-filewriter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create new lines, simply append a newline character to the end of the string:

```
FileWriter writer = ...
writer.write("The line\n");
```

Also, the `PrintWriter` class provides methods which automatically append newline characters for you (**edit:** it will also automatically use the correct newline string for your OS):

```
PrintWriter writer = ...
writer.println("The line");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a BufferedWriter and use writer.newLine() after every write-operation that represents one line.

Or, use a PrintWriter and writer.println().

Comment: `.newLine()` will choose the platform-specific newline for you as well.

Comment: Ohhh, okay.  I gotcha.  So FileWriter isn't really the best for writing to a text file?

Comment: PrintWriter is the good for writing to a file. At least if you want to write raw data. But since you actually want to print text to a file, wrapping the FileWriter into a BufferedWriter or PrintWriter helps you dealing with that.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral I think `PrintWriter` is the best choice for writing text to a file because, in addition to providing methods that write `String` objects, it provides methods that write other data types like `int`, `float`, and `double`.  To output an `int` with `FileWriter`, you would have to convert it to a String: `writer.write(myInt + "");`.  With `PrintWriter`, you can just do `writer.print(myInt);`.  This is a small convenience, but a convenience nonetheless.  `PrintWriter` also provides the `println()` methods, which automatically include a newline at the end.

Comment: @Michael Okay, that makes sense.  I chose FileWriter because the Java book I have uses it.  I will remember that for the future, thank you!!!

Comment: @Polygnome No, all `Writer` classes, including `PrintWriter` are designed for writing **text** to an output stream.  If you want to write binary data, you should use a "regular" `OutputStream` object like `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: All users of `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` must remember that they swallow exceptions, and proceed accordingly. For this reason they are no appropriate for use over a network, or for any other situation where you need to know not only that there was an error during writing but also what it actually was.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `BufferedWriter` then you can use an inbuilt method :

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(output, charset);
writer.newLine();
```